# rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome Could not parse version constraint v4.1.*: Invalid version string "v4.1.*"

Tags: yii2, font-awesome, adminlte

I can't update my composer packages, error:

```
 Could not load package rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome in http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint v4.1.*: Invalid version string "v4.1.*"
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thans, but the problem is solved with "composer self-update"

Answer (score 0):

`composer self-update` helped. Problem solved

Comment: Please explain how this solved your problem, why this works, etc. Simply posting a code fragment is not informative.